# Key server receive failed when installing through PPA

Tags: apt, ppa, 16.10, pantheon, keyserver

I'm fairly new to Linux. I have Ubuntu, and now I want to install the Pantheon desktop, but as soon I run the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
```

I get an error message saying:

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
```

I have tried looking up a solution to the problem online, but I couldn't find any solution that worked for me. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any firewall set? In such case, momentarily disable the firewall and try to add the PPA again

Comment: @M.Becerra I disabled the firewall, but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Are you behind a (transparent) HTTP proxy server? Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX gpg --batch --no-tty --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --search-keys 0x6C8769CEDC20F5E66C3B7D37BF36996C4E1F8A59` and `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX wget -O /dev/null 'http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xBF36996C4E1F8A59'`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the manual way,

1. Open terminal and open sources list:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Add the lines: Look your ubuntu version and change **zesty** to
   yours.

   ```
   deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/daily/ubuntu zesty main 
   deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/daily/ubuntu zesty main
   ```
3. Add key:

   ```
    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4E1F8A59
   ```
4. Run command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

Now you can install packages from this repo.

This is a template to add any repository from ppa.

[image: PPA manual repository installation]

Comment: `add-apt-repository` has `--keyserver` option, too.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same issue. I am not behind a firewall, but need to use a HTTP proxy. It seems `gpg` does not honour these settings, at least not when invoked through `add-apt-repository`. So, the solution for me was to get on a network without need for a proxy; of course, that may not be possible for everybody.

Comment: Care to comment on the downvote, perhaps?