# Cannot add PPA on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome-terminal, ppa, 17.10, proxy

Whenever I try to add PPA, I am getting and error. Below is one such case.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3  
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~webupd8team/ubuntu/sublime-text-3'.
ERROR: '~webupd8team' user or team does not exist.
```

I am using an institution HTTP proxy. I have tried setting HTTP_PROXY and ALL_PROXY in the environment without any success. Also, I have tried out the other solutions in other questions with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this PPA manually with

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu artful main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu artful main 

EOF
```

and add its GPG key with

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
```

or

```
sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  EEA14886
sudo gpg -a --export EEA14886 | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

or (with your proxy address and its port in the command)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com \
     --keyserver-options http-proxy=http://proxy_address:proxy_port \
     --recv-keys EEA14886
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and so on.

Note: this answer is based on these : [first](https://askubuntu.com/a/912400/66509), [second](https://askubuntu.com/a/15272/66509) and [third](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361220/57134).

**Update:** 
try to get and install the package manually

```
cd /tmp
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sublime-text-installer/sublime-text-installer_3126-2~webupd8~1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./sublime-text-installer_3126-2~webupd8~1_all.deb
```

Comment: The first command ran pretty well. But then, this is what I got. https://imgur.com/a/O2th8

Comment: I updated my answer, you can try pgpkeys.mit.edu method above.

Comment: gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/somnath/.gnupg' and 
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available is what I get

Comment: Try last one with proxy settings in the command line. Replace *proxy_address:proxy_port* with your values and try.

Comment: Still, getting the same result. https://imgur.com/a/LXYqD

Comment: Hi @N0rbert, can you please help me?

Comment: I have three new ideas: download GPG key while connected to the 3G/4G mobile internet (Wi-Fi hotspot on phone should be enabled), VPN, or try to setup local tor proxy.

Comment: Same result coming for all 3. :(

Comment: @SomnathRakshit please read my update above.